# yii2 hidden input field using javascript append and get it from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to yii2. Appreciate if someone could help me solved a problem.

I am trying to append a hidden input field to my form using javascript (not link with model). After which, when I submit, get it from controller. However, there seem to be some mistake i did. Please advise and show me the correct code. The following is my code:

Javascript

```
var div_input = $('#div_hidden_input');
div_input.append('<input type="hidden" id="input1" value="value1" />');
```

Controller

```
if (!empty($_POST["input1"]))
{
    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', "in");
}else{
    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'out');
}
```

It always go into the else statement. I inspect the html code, the appended hidden field is there. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given name attribute to it:

```
var div_input = $('#div_hidden_input');
div_input.append('<input type="hidden" id="input1" value="value1" name="input1"/>');
```